# Playing .swf File on Application Startup

Tags: android, flash

I want my application to look more fancy. For that i have made an animation for the application startup. its in .swf format. I want that whenever the user clicks the application icon on his android device and my application is launched **it plays the animation first and then jumps into the main activity**. How can i accomplish that? the main which i don't know how to do is how to play the animation on the application startup and then jump into main activity! can anybody please explain this with the help of a complete example? am new to android!

Comment: Did you get success in playing .swf file in Android? I have tried the same way as shown in the answer but did not make it work. Can you please share your code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a splash screens does not fit very well in Android but if you want it, you should load it into a WebView :

```
    String localUrl ="file:///android_asset/my_anim.swf";

    WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.anim_webView);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl(localUrl);
```

Comment: can u please re edit your answer and explain things in detail?? how will i play the animation and then jump into main activity?? whats the role of url?? can't i just place my .swf in project and access it from there?

Comment: If it's a splash screen, the best way to jump into activity after is with a timer of the duration of the animation. Double check the URL I have posted, the file IS inside your project, in the assets folder.

Comment: and whats the role of webview?

Comment: Remember that swf file is web component, which can be displayed via webView. It has a lot of disadvatanges, i.e. a lot a devices don't support flash, so your animations will be not visible.

Comment: any workaround for that?? secondly do i have to add any specific permissions??

Comment: First of all, a splash screens does not fit very well in Android but if you want it, you should load it into a WebView. did not understand this